# Bumping Series and its Formula

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I was thinking of random series, popping up in mind, when I thought of one possible series in my head. It is as follows:

[image]

The basic idea is, take a line of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ which goes till infinity, and add them. One visible thing here is that the most maximum highest number $\mathbb{N}_{max}$ would be $\mathbb{N}_{i}$. In basic words, if we go till number 5, $\mathbb{N}_5$ then the height it reaches by summation is 5.

Further, carrying on, we can get:

[image: image1]

The basic implication here is that we bump the numbers by specific $\mathbb{N}$. At start, we take the beginning number, in our case it is 1, we move once up and then once down. Then we do it twice, thrice and so on. So `1 3 2` according to my diagram is one bump. At the ending $\mathbb{N}$ which is 2 here, we will jump it by 2 and make it low by 2. So it gets `2 5 12 7 4`. Here, assume $\mathbb{N}_i$ as the number of incrementation, before it was 1, now it is 2. We get different sets, with different terms, but total number of terms we get through this would be $2 \mathbb{N}_i + 1$. Now, it will start from 4, go on making 3 jumps before landing by three terms. By this, we get series highlighted by circles in that triangular array as:

```
1, 3, 2, 5, 12, 7, 4, 9, 20, 44, 24, 13, 7, 15, 32, 68, 144, 76, 40, 21, 11, 23, 48, 100, 208, 432, 224, 116, 60, 31, 16...
```

The series seem to be divergent, my specific question here is how to represent this series in Mathematical terms. Can there be a formula to guess the next number or any probability test?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: thanks so much @JoséCarlosSantos I will start learning it

Comment: When you are dealing with series, you should always start by checking the database of sequences https://oeis.org/. I checked it and did not find any sequence (series) with the terms you listed. So the sequence is unknown and it will most probably be difficult to figure out the math behind it.

Comment: Please just tell me @user25406 that it will go in Millennium Prize Problem or solution to it will make finder a Abel Prize :D

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question.

Comment: My comment or the question itself @user25406 ?

Comment: Let me add also some tags, probability, any ideas of more relevant tags? More tags help

Comment: Both, the question and the comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143187/discussion-between-aira-thunberg-and-user25406).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A053218 for the triangle and https://oeis.org/A152920 for the formula.

Comment: I don't know why a lot of people generally recommend me OEIS but @R.J.Mathar I honestly hate OEIS a lot. It does not contain the series I made but additionally I saw its just politics. Whomever is the puppet of Neil Sloane gets it. But still, I am not going to upload this series on OEIS, I allow anyone to do it without citing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given by
$$a_n=\begin{cases}(n+1)\cdot 2^{n-\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil^2+\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil-2}&\text{if $\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil\leqslant \left\lfloor\dfrac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$}
\\\\(n+1)\cdot 2^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor-n}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

*Proof* :

- Let us call $a_m,a_{m+1},\cdots, a_{m+j}$ "increasing part" if, for $i=m,m+1,\cdots, m+j-1$, $a_{i+1}-a_i\gt 0$ hold. For example, the numbers in the "increasing part" of the second line are $a_2=3,a_4=5,a_8=9,a_{14}=15,\cdots$. Then, we can say that the numbers in the "increasing part" of the $M$-th line are $$a_{N^2-N+M}=(N^2-N+M+1)\cdot 2^{M-2}\qquad (N\geqslant M-1)\tag1$$ In the following, let us prove $(1)$ by induction on $M$. The numbers in the first line are $a_1=1,a_3=2,a_7=4,a_{13}=7,\cdots$. Let $b_1=1,b_2=3,b_3=7,b_4=13,\cdots$. Since $b_{N+1}-b_N=2N$, we have, for $N\geqslant 2$, $b_N=1+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(2k)=N^2-N+1$ which holds for $N=1$. Let $c_1=1,c_2=2,c_3=4,c_4=7,\cdots$. Since $c_{N+1}-c_N=N$, we have, for $N\geqslant 2$, $c_N=1+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}k=(N^2-N+2)/2$ which holds for $N=1$. So, The numbers in the first line are $a_{N^2-N+1}=(N^2-N+2)/2$, which means that, for $M=1$, $(1)$ holds. Suppose that $(1)$ holds for $M$. Then, since the difference of the numbers of the $M$-th line is $2^{M-1}$, we have $$\begin{align}a_{N^2-N+M+1}&=a_{N^2-N+M}+(a_{N^2-N+M}+2^{M-1})
  \\\\&=2\times (N^2-N+M+1)\cdot 2^{M-2} +2^{M-1}\\\\&=(N^2-N+M+2)\cdot 2^{M-1}\end{align}$$
  as long as $N\geqslant M$.
- Let us call $a_m,a_{m+1},\cdots, a_{m+j}$ "decreasing part" if, for $i=m,m+1,\cdots, m+j-1$, $a_{i+1}-a_i\lt 0$ hold. Also, let us call $a_2=3,a_5=12,a_{10}=44,a_{17}=144,\cdots$ "top of triangles". For example, the numbers in the "decreasing part" of the second line (counted from the top of triangles) are $a_3=2,a_6=7,a_{11}=24,a_{18}=76,\cdots$. Then, we can say that the numbers in the "decreasing part" of the $M$-th line (counted from the top of triangles) are $$a_{N^2+M}=(N^2+M+1)\cdot 2^{N-M}\qquad (N\geqslant M-1)\tag2$$ In the following, let us prove $(2)$ by induction on $M$. Substituting $M=N+1$ into $(1)$ gives $a_{N^2+1}=(N^2+2)\cdot 2^{N-1}$, which means that, for $M=1$, $(2)$ holds. Suppose that $(2)$ holds for $M$. Then, since the difference of the numbers of the $(M+1)$-th line (counted from the top of triangles) is $2^{N-M}$, we have $$\begin{align}a_{N^2+M+1}&=(a_{N^2+M}+2^{N-M})\div 2\\\\&=\bigg((N^2+M+1)\cdot 2^{N-M}+2^{N-M}\bigg)\div 2
  \\\\&=(N^2+M+2)\cdot 2^{N-M-1}\end{align}$$ as long as $N\geqslant M$.

Finally, let us try to represent $a_n$ by $n$ using $(1)(2)$.

- For a given $n$, solving $n=N^2-N+M$, we get $M=n-N^2+N$. Since $n-N^2+N-1=M-1\leqslant N$, solving $N^2\geqslant n-1$ gives $N\geqslant\sqrt{n-1}$. Since $1\leqslant M=n-N^2+N$, solving $N^2-N+1-n\leqslant 0$ gives $N\leqslant \frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}$. Therefore, for a given $n$, we have $M=n-N^2+N$ and $\sqrt{n-1}\leqslant N\leqslant \frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}$, so we can take $N=\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil$ if there is such an $N$.
- For a given $n$, solving $n=N^2+M$, we get $M=n-N^2$. Since $n-N^2-1=M-1\leqslant N$, solving $N^2+N-n+1\geqslant 0$ gives $N\geqslant \frac{-1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}$. Since $1\leqslant M=n-N^2$, solving $N^2\leqslant n-1$ gives $N\leqslant \sqrt{n-1}$. Therefore, for a given $n$, we have $M=n-N^2$ and $\frac{-1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\leqslant N\leqslant\sqrt{n-1}$, so we can take $N=\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor$ if there is such an $N$.

In conclusion, we have
$$a_n=\begin{cases}(n+1)\cdot 2^{n-\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil^2+\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil-2}&\text{if $\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil\leqslant \left\lfloor\dfrac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$}
\\\\(n+1)\cdot 2^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor-n}&\text{otherwise}.\quad\blacksquare\end{cases}$$

---

$a_n$ can be written as
$$a_n=(n+1)\cdot 2^{n-\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil^2+\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil-2}\small\max\bigg(\min\bigg(\left\lfloor\dfrac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil+1,1\bigg),0\bigg)$$
$$+(n+1)\cdot 2^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\right\rfloor-n}\small\bigg(1-\max\bigg(\min\bigg(\left\lfloor\dfrac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\sqrt{n-1}\right\rceil+1,1\bigg),0\bigg)\bigg)$$

Comment: Just what i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

The $m$-th term of the $n$-th line of that "triangle" is $u_{n,m} = \sum_{k=0}^n (m+k){n\choose k} = 2^{n-1}(2m+n)$ (you can check this by induction).

Then all that is left is writing $m$ and $n$ in terms of the $k$-th number of the series so that $v_k = u_{n(k), m(k)}$.